# Requests: Proxy not working in people_also_ask module

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I am scraping search results from google using people_also_ask module. The module itself dont have method to use proxies but I manually added proxies in the module. When I got blocked from google I printed the status and it was printing my ip address was banned from sending requests. The code I added in people_also_ask module to use proxies is

```
            proxies = {
                    'http' : "http://username:passward@ip:port"
                        }
            response = SESSION.get(URL, params=params, headers=HEADERS, proxies=proxies)
```

.I know it is an illegal activity but I want to know why it happens for education purpose mainly. I think the code to extract the data is irrelevant so I am adding simple code to send request using people_also_ask module

```
import people_also_ask as paa
queries = ["how to boil eggs","how to make cake","price of poco f1","price of wooden table","best soap in us","how much tesla worth"]
for query in queries:
    questions = paa.get_related_questions(query ,40)
```

**Note:** The changes are made in first function named search() of google.py of people_also_people module

**Note:** I am doing searchs from browser without any problem. why is google allowing me to use google but blocked from using the script

Comment: when you visit page with browser then it display ads and there is some chance that you click some of them - and Google will earn money. But your script for sure will not load ads and it will not click them so Google will not earn money. And this is why it may block scripts/bots - all for money, for big money, billions dolars.

Comment: Google gives APIs to access they data (Search data, YouTube data, Maps data, etc) without scraping - and this access is not blocked.

Comment: Ya I know but my client cannot pay twice for same thing. Actually I made him scraper to extract 15 questions for a query and there were atleast 1000 queries a day. but when he increased this number to 40 questions he could only get 250. So I was working with proxies and got into this. Good point that I am able to use browser because of the ads

Comment: some portals offers paid proxy servers and they have special servers for scraping Google because it has very complex system to detect scripts/bots - sometimes called `proxy server for SEO` (Google has big money to create complex system which can check many parameters and it may use even Machine Learning (Neural Networks) to detect scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. Although it is a proxy service, it doesn't guarantee 100% anonymity. When you send the HTTP GET request via the proxy server, the request sent by your program to the proxy server is:

```
GET http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.whatsmybrowser.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.10.0
```

Now, when the proxy server sends this request to the actual destination, it sends:

```
GET http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.whatsmybrowser.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.10.0
Via: 1.1 naxserver (squid/3.1.8)
X-Forwarded-For: 122.126.64.43
Cache-Control: max-age=18000
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see, it throws your IP (in my case, 122.126.64.43) in the HTTP header: X-Forwarded-For and hence the website knows that the request was sent on behalf of 122.126.64.43

Read more about this header at: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239

If you want to host your own squid proxy server and want to disable setting X-Forwarded-For header, read: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/

I dont get any credit for the answer I copied this answer from the following post I found [Python Requests module - proxy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961293/python-requests-module-proxy-not-working)